# Why does a python pre-compiled file dissappear after being used?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am taking MIT6.00.2.x, and sometimes psets provide a python pre-compiled file which after some time of being used disappears. Is it an issue of Python 2.7 or is an issue of Python in general?

Comment: `.pyc` files that already exist are not removed by Python during normal operation. But they will be updated if the source file is changed. Most likely something you are doing is removing the file.

Comment: I am using Eclipse to run these files, and after closing Eclipse, the file no longer exists.